# getNodeName, getLocalName not returning expected values

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-namespaces

I'm parsing a simple XML and try to get at the nodeNames. In some variant of this XML, some nodeNames have a namespace-prefix "mets:". I'm trying to match all "fptr" Elements, whether they have a mets-prefix or not.

Here's an example of the xml, containing both simple fptr Elements and some with prefix:

```
<mets:structMap xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" TYPE="logical" ID="DTL1">
    <div ORDER="1" LABEL="Alle Scans" TYPE="first level" ID="DTL2">
        <div ORDER="1" LABEL="1" TYPE="Seite" ID="DTL3">
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FID00000020" ID="DTL21"/>
        </div>
        <div ORDER="2" LABEL="2" TYPE="Seite" ID="DTL4">
            <mets:fptr FILEID="FID00000021" ID="DTL22"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ORDER="1" LABEL="Hauptdokument - pdf" TYPE="entry" ID="DTL5">
        <fptr FILEID="FID1a" ID="DTL11"/>
    </div>
</mets:structMap>
```

And here's a simple parsing routine that should print out the element names and ns-prefix of all elements:

```
package at.ac.onb.zid.dtlcontent.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class structMapTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        File fXmlFile = new File("src/test/resources/teststructmap.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList elemList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(int i = 0; i<elemList.getLength();i++) {
            Node n = elemList.item(i);
            System.out.println("nodeName=" + n.getNodeName());

            if(n instanceof Element) {
                Element e = (Element) n;
                String eID = e.getAttribute("ID");
                String nsPrefix = e.getPrefix();
                String eLN = e.getLocalName();
                String eNSURI = e.getNamespaceURI(); 

                System.out.println("  ID=" + eID);
                System.out.println("  prefix=" + nsPrefix);
                System.out.println("  localName=" + eLN);
                System.out.println("  nsURI=" + eNSURI);
                System.out.println("");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it prints out though:

```
nodeName=mets:structMap
  ID=DTL1
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=div
  ID=DTL2
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=div
  ID=DTL3
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=mets:fptr
  ID=DTL21
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=div
  ID=DTL4
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=mets:fptr
  ID=DTL22
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=div
  ID=DTL5
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null

nodeName=fptr
  ID=DTL11
  prefix=null
  localName=null
  nsURI=null
```

All the prefix values are null. I expected the first two fptr-prefixes (of ID=DTL21 and DTL22) to be "mets".

Same with the localName: I expected all the fptr-localNames to be "fptr", instead they are all null. Similar with the namespace-URI.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set `dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);` before trying to work with XML with namespaces in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspected something like this, but didn't even know where to begin to look... that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

XML namespaces are perfectly sensible, as is much of XML design and indeed like much of XML design can be a real pain in the arse when dealing with it directly in code. In your example both the prefixed and non-prefixed elements are actually the same namespace URL, so you shouldn't really be having any issue at all.

Java 8 library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics) ignores namespace by default (but can be explicit if desired, ie in the rare cases when it actually matters). The library isn't a query language, simply a pretty direct way of dealing with dynamic structures. As such recursion is easy, so we can scan all elements thusly:

```
{
    XmlDynamic example = new XmlDynamic(xmlStringOrReaderOrInputSourceEtc);

    List<String> ids = allElements(example)
        .filter(hasElementName("fptr")) // import static alexh.weak.XmlDynamic.hasElementName;
        .map(fptr -> fptr.get("@ID").asString())
        .collect(toList());
    // [DTL21, DTL22, DTL11]
}

/** recursively stream all elements */
Stream<Dynamic> allElements(Dynamic root) {
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(root), root.children().flatMap(child -> allElements(child)));
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Did you write that lib?

Comment: @jackthehipster Yep. It's actually a general purpose library for working with nested weakly typed data, XmlDynamic is a specialised implementation for XML. See the github if you're interested in source & docs https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics#xml-dynamics